# Cloning of Set interface

Tags: java, set

I have a class which looks as follows.

```
class ClassName{
    private Set<String> set;

    public ClassName(Set<String> set){
        this.set=set;
    }

    public Set<String> getSet(){
        return set;
    }
}
```

I want to return the clone of the set  through the getter and not the reference to the set itself. Since, set is an interface, it does not have a clone method.

```
class User{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashSet<String> hs=new HashSet<String>();
        hs.add("str1");
        hs.add("str2");
        ClassName cn=new ClassName(hs);
        HashSet<String> newHS=cn.getSet();
        newHS.add("str3");
    }
}
```

If I return reference to the set itself, then the method getting the Set could add or delete from the Set which is not favorable like in the above class User. Can anyone suggest a way to clone the set?

The reason for using a Set and not a HashSet or TreeSet is because this would make the ClassName reusable as I do not have to change the ClassName when I decide to use a different kind of a Set in future.

Comment: `.clone()` is broken in Java, always has been always will be, you don't ever want to use `.clone()`. It seems you really just want an `ImmutableSet` view of the backing set.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't want to pull in additional libraries, then you should copy the set in constructor, and in getter return `unmodifiableSet`.

```
class ClassName{
    private Set<String> set;

    public ClassName(Set<String> set){
        this.set= new HashSet<>(set);
    }

    public Set<String> getSet(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(set);
    }
}
```

If you have Guava library on your classpath, or don't mind adding dependency in your project, then there is a much better option of using `ImmutableSet` as a member variable.

```
class ClassName{
    private ImmutableSet<String> set;

    public ClassName(Set<String> set){
        this.set= ImmutableSet.copyOf(set);
    }

    public ImmutableSet<String> getSet(){
        return set;
    }
}
```